# Vuetify not being applied in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have Vuetify installed in my Laravel project but none of the v- classes are working. There are no errors in the console though. Here is the app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.component('container-component', require('./components/ContainerComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('index-component', require('./components/IndexComponent.vue').default);

const vuetify = new Vuetify();

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify
});
```

and an example component which vuetify isn't being applied to:

```
<template>
    <v-btn>BUTTON</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "IndexComponent"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I just was using a single button to test if it was working.

Comment: You are missing the render function when you create your vue instance.
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

Comment: When I include that line I get error: ReferenceError: App is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your Vue istance you must create a new istance of Vuetify also.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

I suggest you also to add this after importing Vuetify:

`import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'`