# front end not shaping in laravel 6.2

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, laravel-6.2

I used laravel 6.2 and vuetify. But, my vuetify not working. i don't see any design for vuejs. And There is no any mistake  What did i wrong??. Please help me.

```
"vuetify": "^2.1.12"  

"laravel/framework": "^6.2"
```

Below code is my script:

```
app.js

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)


Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Using app.scss in bootstrap:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons');

@import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
```

following code is my web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
    <div id ="app">
        <v-toolbar>
            <v-toolbar-items>
              <v-btn text>Link one</v-btn>
              <v-btn text>Link two</v-btn>
              <v-btn text>Link three</v-btn>
            </v-toolbar-items>
    <script> src ="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you ran `npm run dev` ?

Comment: Yes, There is no any error.

Comment: Is the `HTML` code that you wrote is a vue template or a blade file?

Comment: This is blade file.  https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars#toolbars on the following link. But, I was write below line  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">, <script> src ="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" </script>

Comment: That is wrong you should create a vue template first and then include it in your blade file and then run npm run dev

Comment: Please give me any tutorial link.

Answer (score 0):

First in `assets/js/components` folder create a new file called `Navbar.vue`. Then in `Navbar.vue` write

```
<template>
<v-toolbar>
  <v-toolbar-items>
    <v-btn text>Link one</v-btn>
    <v-btn text>Link two</v-btn>
    <v-btn text>Link three</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</template>
<script>
</script>
```

In you `app.js` add newly created component like so

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Then in your `index.blade.php` file change it to the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="app">
      <navbar></navbar>
    </div>
    <script> src ="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally run `npm run dev`. Visit the page and now you should be able to see everything as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59090760/11008999), in Vuetify 2 when you create your Vue istance you must create a new istance of Vuetify also.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

I suggest you also to add this after importing Vuetify:

```js
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```